# Chrome Omnibox interrupts typing, focus jumps to instant search

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, google-search

My Chrome Omnibox intermittently interrupts my typing, performs google instant search, and moves the focus off of the omnibox, preventing me from continuing to type. Is there a setting that I can change to prevent focus from shifting and my typing from being interrupted?

Example, if I start typing 'face the ', the omnibox autocomplete shows 'facebook.com' and shows instant search normally until I type the 't', then autocomplete shows 'face the nation' and acts as if I had pressed Enter. The Omnibox changes to show a google search URL and focus goes away, preventing me from finishing typing.

Any suggestions to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I just noticed this happening today to me as well

Comment: The same thing is happening to me on my Chrome Browser `Version 27.0.1453.110 m` IT'S EXTREMELY ANNOYING! Anyone know a way to revert versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you guys are on Chrome v28.0.xxxx (type `about:version` in omnibox), it appears to be a bug.  My version 27.0.xxxx doesn't do that.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=247024

Edit: Some users experiencing it on version 27.0.xxx, so it's not that!
Proposed fix/workaround from link above:

> If you're still seeing the issue, and you haven't already done so,
>   follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click the Settings menu in Chrome (three stacked horizontal lines).
> 2. Click Settings from the menu.
> 3. Under the "Search" section, make sure that "Enable Instant for faster searching (omnibox input may be logged)" is unchecked.

Comment: I'm on `Version 27.0.1453.110 m` and it does it to me. And I don't wanna undo the instant search, it was a good feature as it would jump to sites before and sometimes i'd wanna stop typing, but this is just annoying!